# How to multiply certain values of a column by a constant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     product     score
0    1179160  0.424654
1    1066490  0.424509
2    1148126  0.422207
3    1069104  0.420455
4    1069105  0.414603
..       ...       ...
491  1160330  0.168784
492  1069098  0.168749
493  1077784  0.168738
494  1193369  0.168703
495  1179741  0.168684
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to multiply certain score values corresponding to specific products by a constant.
I have the products target of this multiplication in a list like this: [1069104, 1069105] (this is just a simplified
example, in reality it would be more than two products) and my goal is to obtain this:

Multiply scores corresponding to products 1069104 and 1069105 by 10:

```
     product     score
0    1179160  0.424654
1    1066490  0.424509
2    1148126  0.422207
3    1069104  4.204550
4    1069105  4.146030
..       ...       ...
491  1160330  0.168784
492  1069098  0.168749
493  1077784  0.168738
494  1193369  0.168703
495  1179741  0.168684
```

I know that exists DataFrame.multiply but checking the examples it works for full columns, and I just one to change those specific values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing and `isin`:

```
prod_list =  [1069104, 1069105]
df.loc[df['product'].isin(prod_list), 'score'] *= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` functionality ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html))-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [3, 'b']], columns=['num', 'c'])
df.loc[df.c == 'a', 'num'] =  df.num * 10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use if condition with for loop to multiply the specific values

```
for i in range (len(df)):
    `if((df[colun]==1069104) or (df[colun]==1069105)):
          df[score]=df[score]*10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Make data
df = pd.DataFrame({'product': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'score': [0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1]})

# List of products to change
product_list = [8,4]

for product_no in product_list:                    # Loop though product numbers
    product = df.loc[df['product'] == product_no]  # Find the product corresponding to given product number
    score = product["score"].values[0]             # Extract the score for the given product number

    print(score*10)                                # Modify score as you please

    df.at[product.index[0], "score"] = score*10    # If you want to modify the dataframe with the new value

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try to do so in future.